# How to check opinion between any two arbitrary people?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

It's easy enough to check an individual's opinion of you, and their opinion of their liege. But what about their opinion of someone else?

For example, say you as a king want to decide how to distribute duchies. You might want to grant them to two individuals who like each other so the realm is more stable, or to two individuals who loathe each other so they won't jointly rebel against you. Since one is not the liege of the other, how do you check their opinions of one another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature has been made a bit obscure, but it is possible. Go to the character's screen then right click on their portrait. Now two buttons will appear, one with a head and one that is for diplomacy. *Right* click on the head button. Now three more buttons appear, the bottom one is for checking character's relations. You will then get the usual list of people, but opinions will be of the character you selected rather than of yourself.

Comment: I knew the UI had a steep learning curve, but I keep learning new things. I just confirmed this!